# Dynamic report not compiling even after adding commons-logging-1.1.1.jar in the class path ,its throwing Exception

Tags: java, jar, dynamic-reports

Am trying to create a Blank Pdf in my home directory,am using dynamicreports-core-2.4.1.jar for creating dynamic report.when i try to run my java file i get the following exception.pls help!

> Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.base.component.DRList.setType(DRList.java:79)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.base.component.DRList.<init>(DRList.java:52)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.base.DRBand.<init>(DRBand.java:42)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.base.DRReport.init(DRReport.java:138)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.base.DRReport.<init>(DRReport.java:120)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.ReportBuilder.<init>(ReportBuilder.java:74)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.<init>(JasperReportBuilder.java:117)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.report(DynamicReports.java:120)
    at com.unify.avcv.utils.threads.DynamicReportsGeneration.main(DynamicReportsGeneration.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

> Java Code

```
package com.unify.avcv.utils.threads;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.*;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.exception.DRException;
public class DynamicReportsGeneration {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, DRException {

        JasperReportBuilder report=DynamicReports.report();
        report.toPdf(new  FileOutputStream(new File("/home/sethuraman")));
        System.out.println("done!");

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you also add commons-lang3.jar ?

Comment: oops no,is it required?

Answer (score 1):

You should to add `common-lang3.jar` into your build path since trhe dynamicreports jar is using `Validate` class from `common-lang3.jar`.